# Java RSA - Constructing public key using modulus string and public exponent string

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I have this code:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(keySize);
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
System.out.println("publicKey:" + publicKey);
```

the output for a run:

```
publicKey:Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
    modulus: 91026765002706288867763671707890256444556491085864843097606069886752641850958968402542910033341226293747620290679011468803812135644603615727909010737368199182137517524592490628443269825314162441969081210450684647396205652070736268541584184960515476448786428782291670074320598962297519615175082972099164486927
    public exponent: 65537
```

Now I want to construct the key to decrypt as following:

```
RSAPublicKeySpec publicSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(modulusStr, 16), new BigInteger(publicExponentStr, 16));
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pupKey = factory.generatePublic(publicSpec);

System.out.println("publicKey:" + pupKey);
```

But the output is different:

```
publicKey:Sun RSA public key, 1232 bits


     modulus: 43045393507044718977987783526170006227729098917076727528691078730555395085202306732993768634230789938109087426142463574995910150627330334608775595737083465581426001237091137474842776120780697084545110477342521432568680506316814949888900358728179483490979805640521767456573703418040730841096209231624036816985022810174297855365613680959673590517874895661273111176382128521
     public exponent: 415031
```

Shouldn't I get the same output?

Comment: the modulus and public exponent are printed in base 10,  but you constructed the bigintegers assuming they were base 16.

Comment: You are correct @JamesKPolk, I changed it to base 10 and it is working!